# Isomorphism of all Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

my work book has a questions that asked us to prove something, however the answer was not provided. The question states that:

Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over $F$ where the $dim(V) = n, dim(W) = m$. Proof that the set of all linear transformation from $V$ to  $W$ (denoted by $L$) is isomorphic to the set of $m \times n$ matrices over $F$ with the matrix representation a[L]b.

So basically, the first step I have done is define

f: L -> M mxn (F) where L are all the linear transformation from V - W. However, I am stumped. I am unsure of how to define f to relate L to our matrices. I need that information in order to proof that it is linear and bijective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix isomorphisms $\mathbb{R}^n\to V$ and $W\to \mathbb{R}^m$, and consider the following commutative diagram:

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\operatorname{Hom}(V,W) @>>> \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^n,W);\\
@VVV @VVV \\
\operatorname{Hom}(V,\mathbb{R}^m) @>>> \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m);
\end{CD}$$

By the Yoneda embeddings, the edges of this square are isomorphisms, so the diagonal $\operatorname{Hom}(V,W)\to \operatorname{Hom}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)\cong M_{m\times n} (F)$ is also.

Comment: I'm clearly in a strange mood this evening, but hopefully _somebody_ will find this useful.

Comment: It makes for [interesting reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hom_functor), at the very least. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

can you see that the given space is nothing but the space of $m\times n$ real matrices?As you fix a basis for $V$ and $W$, each linear transformation is expressible as an $m\times n$ matrix acting on the right of row vectors of length $n$.Now define a natural isomorphism between your space and the space of $m\times n$ real matrices